# Even though I have autowired the entity in my ServiceImpl class, its still giving me the error related to autowire

Tags: java, spring, autowired

This is my Impl Class

```
@Service
public class TransactionServiceImpl implements TransactionService{

    @Autowired
    private Customer customer;
```

This is the error I am getting

```
Field customer in com.rewardsystem.AugustStore.service.TransactionServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.rewardsystem.AugustStore.entities.Customer' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.rewardsystem.AugustStore.entities.Customer' in your configuration.
```

I tried to redo the steps but the problem still arises

Comment: show the code in class Customer im almost sure thats an entity just by the error but still show the code

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you are trying to autowire `Customer` class that is Entity class (as per error message) and Entity classes are not beans (annotated with **@Service**, **@Component**, **@Configuration**, **@Repository** and **@Bean**). So you can't use them as a dependency in other classes by using **@Autowired** annotation.

So please remove **@Autowired** annotation on top `Customer` class and create instance using new operator like this

```
Customer customer=new Customer();
```